# Ibus color-icons

Tags: icons, ibus

I'm using Ibus to enjoy some layouts and still it works great. However sometimes I notice that the icon of some of my typing input methods can not be displayed. Reboot fix the issue but it's like a wildcard, happens once in a while. Is there a way to permanently fix it ?
(I'm using Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to *permanently* fix this, but all you need to do is restart ibus, by clicking the icon on your panel (assuming you have it there) and clicking restart.

If you don't have the icon there, follow this:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
- type `killall ibus-daemon` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
- type `ibus-daemon` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Your icons should show up as usual now.

Comment: Thanks. Hope that they can fix this soon. For now I'll follow your wisdom.